# PDF Dowload or Intent

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` that retrieve two `TextViews` from the Cloud Firestore and whenever I click on the card, I want it, based on the `pdfUrl` stored in my Firestore database, that an activity be opened with the pdf or donwload the pdf to the phone. But I don't know how to achieve that.

[Here's my firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcjGH.png)

My code:

```
public class RecylerViewTestsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<uploadTests, TestesViewHolder> adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyler_view_tests);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTests);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = rootRef.collection("FilterPDFUploads");


    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<uploadTests> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<uploadTests>()
            .setQuery(query, uploadTests.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<uploadTests,TestesViewHolder >(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TestesViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull uploadTests model) {
            holder.setTestesDesc(model.getDescription());
            holder.setTestesName(model.getUsername());

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public TestesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pdf_tests_items, parent, false);
            return new TestesViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}

//////////////////////////VIEW HOLDER////////////////////////////////////////////

private class TestesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;
    private CardView itemsCard;

    TestesViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;

    }

    void setTestesDesc (String descri) {
        TextView desc = view.findViewById(R.id.teste_description);
        desc.setText(descri);
    }
    void setTestesName (String username) {
        TextView user = view.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
        user.setText(username);
    }
    void setPdfUrl(final String url){

    }
}

//////////////////////////VIEW HOLDER////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whenever I click on the card, I want it, based on the pdfUrl stored in my firestore database, that an activity be opened with the pdf or donwload the pdf to the phone

To solve this, you should use `setOnClickListener()` on your `TestesViewHolder` object. Inside the click listener, please add the following lines of code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Where `url` is the actual url that is stored in your database. That's it!

Comment: Thank you, the solution  worked.
But if the user does not have a pdf viewer installed on the phone he can see the pdf?

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho No, the user should have a PDF viewer in order to see it properly.